# How to set a LinearGradient as Scaffold background

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm working on an app, where the "header" is a `LinearGradient` (contained in the body of my `Scaffold`), unfortunately, when I scroll down to use my `RefreshIndicator` widget, the background of my app is white. I would like that my `LinearGradient` continue where is the white area.

I tried to mess with the options of my `Scaffold` widget as well as the `ThemeData` but I didn't find the right property.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is an option to set the background color of a Scaffold to a LinearGradient. You could however wrap the Scaffold widget with a Container and set the LinearGradient on the container. Then, by setting the background color of the Scaffold to transparent the container will become visible.

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: ...,
  ),
  child: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
),
```